# Error in very similar functions while manipulating strings in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I am learning C and I came across a problem while manipulating strings.
In a problem I was solving I was supposed to write a function to take a string and a character and delete all occurrences of the given character, and then I had to return the modified string.
The function I wrote is this:

```
char *strdelc3(char *s, char ch){
for(int i=0,j=0; i!=strlen(s)+1; ++i)
 if(s[i]!=ch){
  s[j]=s[i];
  ++j;
 }
return s;
}
```

And when I pass a string and a character as arguments:

```
main(){
char s[20]="mary";
puts(strdelc3(s,'r'));
}
The output is: Segmentation fault(core dumped),
```

which by my research means I am accessing memory that does not belong to me.
The solutions had this code:

```
char *strdelc4(char *s, char ch){ /*Correct*/
int i,j;
for(i=0, j=0; s[i]!='\0'; ++i)
 if(s[i]!=ch){
  s[j]=s[i];
  ++j;
 }
s[j]='\0';
return s;
}
```

Which is basically equal to mine, however this piece works fine!
Since the two codes are so similar I don't see anything wrong with mine...
I have already studied both but I don't see what is the problem with mine... Could someone help?

Comment: Why `i!=strlen(s)+1` in the first example? I think that's where the problem is. Why add one?

Comment: There are two differences between the functions. Try them one by one to see why each one introduces a different problem.

Comment: The problem is that when `i` is `strlen(s)`, you'll move the zero byte, and the string length will decrease, so `i` will never be equal to `strlen(s)+1`. It's always a bad idea to put `strlen` in a loop conditional (it's a huge waste of time). But in this case, it's especially bad.

Comment: Anyway, take a simple string few characters long and run your program on it with a debugger. This is what we usually do if not able to spot the problem by looking at the code.

Comment: Or forego the indexing and [just use pointers](https://pastebin.com/Lec9GexD).

Comment: Ahhhh, wow thank you user3386109, now I understand! when i=5, strlen(s)+1=4, and i will keep on increasing without being equal to my condition.

Comment: Thank you all who responded in such a short time. The other suggestions are great. I can't still use a debugger but someday I will try.

Comment: Related Q&A that has a similar correct solution to properly process a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422565/write-a-c-program-which-capitalizes-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentenc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your loop conditional:

```
i!=strlen(s)+1
```

You're attempting to use `strlen(s)+1` here to avoid having to add the null byte.  But in doing so, `strlen(s)` changes once you move the terminating null byte.

On the first 4 iterations through the loop, `strlen(s)` is 4.  On the next iteration, `i` is 4 and `strlen(s)+1` is 5 so you enter the loop again.  You then move the null byte.  Now on the following iteration, `strlen(s)` is 3 and `i` is 5.  The conditional is still true so you keep going, walking off the end of the string.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes a crash.

The second piece of code addresses this issue by explicitly looking for the null byte based on the index of `i` and appending a null byte to the resulting string after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler version of the code would use the `do - while` loop instead of `for()`:

```c
char *strdelc5idx(char *s, char ch){
    int i=0, j=0;

    do {
        if (s[i] != ch)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    } while (s[i++] != 0);

    return s;
}
```

This will copy the string-terminating NUL character *before* testing it, so you needn't have a separate instruction for it. However, that requires deferring the `i++` incrementation so that the loop condition at the end of an iteration tests the same character which was copied in the iteration. As a result the `i++` and `j++` do no longer appear together, which may make this code less legible at a first glance.

An equivalent pointer version:

```c
char *strdelc5ptr(char *s, char ch){
    char *d = s, *f = s;

    do {
        if (*f != ch)
            *d++ = *f;
    } while (*f++);

    return s;
}
```